# Race condition when setting even listener on frames

Tags: javascript, html, listener, frame

I am trying to set a global keyboard event listener on a page made of frames, and I get a weird behavior when I start typing too early.

The main page looks like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>My title</title>
   </head>
   <frameset rows="*" cols="250,*" framespacing="3" frameborder="yes" border="1" class="doc-result-frameset">
       <frame src="left.html" name="info" id="info" scrolling="auto" class="doc-result-frame-info">
       <frame src="right.html" name="doc" id="doc" class="doc-result-frame-doc">
   </frameset>
   <noframes>&lt;body&gt;&lt;/body&gt;</noframes>
</html>
```

The right frame is a page that takes a lot longer to load than the left frame. The left frame is where I am trying to add some javascript to control the whole page.

I have written the following:

```
top.window.addEventListener("keydown",
   function(event: KeyboardEvent) {handleKeyboardEvent(event, previous, next);},
   true);
var topWindowFrames : Window = top.window.frames;
for (var i = 0; i < topWindowFrames.length; i ++) {
   var frame : Window = topWindowFrames[i];
   frame.onload = (function(frame: Window) {
      return function() {
         frame.document.addEventListener("keydown",
            function(event: KeyboardEvent) {handleKeyboardEvent(event, previous, next);},
            true);};
         })(frame);   
}
```

I have also tried without wrapping the `frame.onload` inside another function, just using `frame` inside the code.

The problem I get is that if I reload the page, and very quickly click on right frame to give it focus and start typing, the left frame's event listener will never work. Conversely, if I wait until everything is loaded to start typing or clicking, everything works fine.

I don't know what goes wrong because I can't seem to find a way to check which listeners are registered for each frame.

Answer (score 0):

trigger the binding of event listeners via body.onLoad

```
<body onLoad="bindEvents()">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try this. I had already executed this code inside a `$(document).ready()` clause. Do you think that would make a difference ?